# JS/jquery: have <li>'s rotate/scale in with delay? Weird CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok, never done anything like this in JS and CSS here but I am trying to achieve this effect with some buttons in a circular expanding div, and a static "x" button in far left that rotates.  https://dribbble.com/shots/3445331-Expanding-Button

For whatever reason I can't get the transition to happen with an increasing delay on each li. What I do is add a "pill" class to both the ul containing the lis (to make them display:none to block) and then to the individual lis.

```js
$('.top-left').hover(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("pill");
  $('.top-left ul').toggleClass("pill");
  $('.top-left img').toggleClass("pill");
  $('.top-left ul li').each(function(i, elem) {
    $(elem).delay(i * 800).toggleClass("pill");
  });
});
```

```css
.top-left ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 35px;
  margin-left: 0;
  display: none;
  transform: translate(20px, -46px);
}

.top-left img {
  margin: auto;
  width: 40px;
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto 10px;
  margin-top: 6px;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 1.4, 1, 1);
  transition-duration: 205ms;
}

.top-left img.pill {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 15px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 1.4, 1, 1);
  transition-duration: 250ms;
}

.top-left ul li {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-right: 10px;
  float: left;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 1.4, 1, 1);
  transition-duration: 250ms;
  transform: scale(0.01,0.01) rotate(-30deg) translate(43px, 0px);
}

.top-left ul li.pill:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.top-left {
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
  border-radius: 55px;
  transition: width ease 0.3s;
  margin-top: 15px;
  background: #4d4d4d;
  border: 4px solid #333;
}

.top-left.pill {
  width: 207px;
}

.top-left ul.pill {
  display: block;
}

.top-left ul li.pill {
  float: left;
  transform: scale(1,1) rotate(0deg) translate(43px, 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="top-left">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="">
  <ul>
    <li value='1'><i class="icon-twitter-sign"></i></li>
    <li value='2'><i class="icon-twitter-sign"></i></li>
    <li value='3'><i class="icon-instagram"></i></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The `li`s show up and in the right place, but no animation occurs, at least that is visible. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add class 'pill' to .top-left :

```
$('.top-left').hover(function () {
  $(this).toggleClass("pill");
}
```

And then you can use this animation with different animation delay for all lis.

```
@keyframes myAnim {
    0% {transform: rotate(90deg) scale(0);}
    100% {transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1);}
}

.top-left.pill ul li:first-child {
     animation: myAnim .25s;
}
.top-left.pill ul li:nth-child(2) {
     animation: myAnim .25s .8s;
}
.top-left.pill ul li:last-child {
     animation: myAnim .25s 1.6s;
}
```

And the rest of the css:

```
.top-left ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 35px;
    /* padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px; */
    margin-left: 0px;
    display: none;
     transform: translate(20px, -46px);
}

.top-left img {
    margin: auto;
    width: 40px;
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto 10px;
    margin-top: 6px;
    /* What transition ? */
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 1.4, 1, 1);
    transition-duration: 250ms;
}

.top-left.pill img {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 15px;
    transform: rotate(90deg);    
}

.top-left ul li {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-right: 10px;
    float: left;
}

.top-left.pill li:hover {
    color: white;
}
.top-left {
    width: 55px;
    height: 55px;
    border-radius: 55px;
    transition: width ease 0.3s;
    margin-top: 15px;
    background: #4d4d4d;
    border: 4px solid #333333;
}

.top-left.pill {
    width: 207px;
}

.top-left.pill ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Only issue is they start as visible with this - I need them to "wink in" - how do I do that?

Comment: Adds forwards at the end of animation call : `animation: myAnim .25s forwards;` to keep the icon in the same state, and applies `transform: scale(0);` at .top-left lis to hide them at the begining